# How to specify dependent features of custom liberty feature

Tags: java, osgi, websphere-liberty, osgi-bundle

I am developing a custom feature with WAB and ServiceBundles. I want to specify the dependent features as well in my feature manifest file.

```
Subsystem-Content: ServiceProvider;version=1.0.0,
 ServiceProviderWeb;version=1.0.0,
 com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0; type="osgi.subsystem.feature",
 com.ibm.wsspi.appserver.webBundle-1.0; type="osgi.subsystem.feature"
```

Is it correct way to do it ? Eclipse Dev tools not giving option to select dependent features (built-in).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for including the `adminCenter-1.0` and `webBundle-1.0` features are correct, since you have listed them as `type="osgi.subsystem.feature"`.

You can inspect other Liberty features for some examples by looking in wlp/lib/features/*.mf.  For example, this is what the webBundle-1.0 feature has currently for `Subsystem-Content`:

```
Subsystem-Content: com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.wab.configure_1.0-javadoc.zip; type=file; location:="dev/spi/ibm/javadoc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.wab.configure_1.0-javadoc.zip",
 com.ibm.websphere.appserver.servlet-3.0; ibm.tolerates:="3.1"; type="osgi.subsystem.feature",
 com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.wab.configure; location:="dev/spi/ibm/,lib/"; type=jar; version="[1.0.0,1.0.200)",
 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.wab; start-phase:=CONTAINER_LATE; version="[1.0.0,1.0.200)",
 com.ibm.ws.eba.wab.integrator; version="[1.0.0,1.0.200)"
```

To break this down line by line:

- includes a javadoc zip from wlp/dev/spi/ibm/javadoc
- includes the serlet-3.0 feature, but also tolerates servlet-3.1
- includes an wab configuration SPI jar at either wlp/dev/spi/ibm/ or wlp/lib/
- includes two other bundles in a similar fashion

You can find official documentation on developing Liberty features here:
[Developing a Liberty feature manually](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_feat_example.html)

Comment: Guiert, thanks for the confirmation. Is there any way to select these features from eclipse dev tools ?? It is showing error (Invalid content entry) if I add any of those features.

Comment: I'm not familiar with developing features via dev tools (I always just use a text editor and duplicate then modify existing features).  I would recommend trying to start a server with your feature enabled and see what happens to check if the errors raised by the IDE are valid or not.  You may also find additional useful docs here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/t_feature_create.html